# Multiple mateials with pointcloudmaterial and linebasicmaterial

Tags: three.js

i like to draw a line with two vertices[10,10,0][-10,-10,0]. i can create a line sucessfully,

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector(10,10,0));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector(-10,-10,0));
geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000, linewidth: 2, side: 2 });
var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
scene.add(line);
```

I like to draw two particle on the vertices of the line,

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector(10,10,0));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector(-10,-10,0));
geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000, linewidth: 2, side: 2 });
var material1 = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial({ color: 0xff0000, size: 3, sizeAttenuation: false });
var materials = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial([material, material1]);
var line = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);
scene.add(line);
```

this method not working, mesh created but not visible in scene. 
can any one give some good suggestion on it..

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK a mesh would need atleast 3 vertices to create a face in a mesh. take a look at the [Line class docs](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Objects/Line) for how to create a line.
eg.

```
var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material )
```

Comment: thanks chris. yes that right, but for creating a line two vertices is enough(starting point and end point),I can easily create a line that's not the problem, creating a particlecloud also not a problem,In THREE.Line we cannot use multipleMaterial, so i guess that creating a mesh is the way to use meshfacematerial.  here my need is multiple material, (i.e) linebasicmaterial and pointcloudmaterial in single mesh or line. my requirement is, a line with two particle at line starting and end point, while i move the particle with mouse event, the line vertices should move to the particle position

Comment: Ahh ok, Ive never actually used the Line class so can not help sorry.